# Invalid scala map.span() function result

Tags: scala

From the code bellow (scala 2.12.2) I would expect to have the following result:

```
(Map(aa -> 1, ab -> 1, ac -> 1),Map(ba -> 2, bb -> 2, bc -> 2))
```

but I am having the following:

```
(Map(),Map(ba -> 2, bc -> 2, ab -> 1, ac -> 1, aa -> 1, bb -> 2))
```

Why am I wrong?

```
scala> val map = Map("aa"->1,"ab"->1,"ac"->1,"ba"->2,"bb"->2,"bc"->2)
map: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(ba -> 2, bc -> 2, ab -> 1, ac -> 1, aa -> 1, bb -> 2)

scala> map.foreach(p=>if (p._1.startsWith("a")) println(p._1))
ab
ac
aa

scala> map.span(p=> p._1.startsWith("a"))
res30: (scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int], scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int]) = (Map(),Map(ba -> 2, bc -> 2, ab -> 1, ac -> 1, aa -> 1, bb -> 2))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`span` *stops* when the given predicate is false, which happens immediately for you because the first key is `"ba"`, which leaves you with an empty `Map`.

You are actually looking for `partition`:

```
scala> val map = Map("aa" -> 1, "ab" -> 1, "ac" -> 1, "ba" -> 2, "bb" -> 2, "bc" -> 2)
map: Map[String,Int] = Map(ba -> 2, bc -> 2, ab -> 1, ac -> 1, aa -> 1, bb -> 2)

scala> map.partition(p => p._1.startsWith("a"))
res1: (Map[String,Int], Map[String,Int]) = (Map(ab -> 1, ac -> 1, aa -> 1),Map(ba -> 2, bc -> 2, bb -> 2))
```

(signatures snipped to make the REPL output more readable)